# Google sheet xpath call out @class

Tags: xpath

How to extract the last update info from this webpage: https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/county-county-breakdown-positive-cases

I tried

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/county-county-breakdown-positive-cases","//div[@class=’wysiwyg--field-webny-wysiwyg-title’]")
```

It didn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/county-county-breakdown-positive-cases","//tbody//tr")
```

Comment: @Kasu - Don't know what to tell you; tried and again and definitely works.

Comment: Hi, It seems your code is to extract the table. I want to extract the last update time, not the table.

Comment: @Kasu - Got it; then your original expression should work. It worked for me.

Comment: Jack, i am getting the error message "Imported Xml content can not be parsed." from my original code

Comment: @kasu - Don't know what to say: this is an exact paste from my sheet `=IMPORTXML(A56,"//div[@class='wysiwyg--field-webny-wysiwyg-title']")` (where `A56` is the URL), and this is a paste of the output: `Last Update: March 26, 2020 | 1:49PM`.